Biasing a varactor diode with AC voltage
I am trying to design a resonant (LC) circuit whose resonant frequency is sensitive to an AC voltage signal so that by tracking changes in resonant frequency I can extract the underlying voltage.
The idea would be to use a varactor diode as the capacitive element in the resonator and bias the diode with the AC voltage to alter it's junction capacitance, thus changing the resonant frequency of the resonator.
The circuit I'd be proposing would basically just be figure 3b in this article.

However, as I read closer, all of the example circuits in the article use a variable DC voltage to tune their varactor junction capacitance—not an AC signal (this signal would have the majority of its spectral power below 500 Hz). When I was thinking about this initially, I was planning on picking the inductor/varactor such that the resonator would be driven at a frequency somewhere in the range of 50-200 MHz, and I figured that compared to such high frequencies, 500 Hz may as well be DC and so this wouldn't matter.
But now, I'm concerned that this circuit won't work for an AC bias signal because an AC signal will bypass the dc blocking capacitor, leading to the varactor not being biased by the AC signal. If that's the case, I have no clue how to change the circuit to bias the varactor—I am not an electrical engineer by training and I am out of my depth. Any help is extremely appreciated.

Why in the world would you want to work with signals in the hundreds of MHz in order to measure the amplitude of a 500 Hz signal? What accuracy are you expecting and what is the range of amplitude for the 500 Hz signal?  Varactor diodes are designed to vary their capacitance in step with a DC voltage and are generally used to make a VCO.  However, at best, the relationship is nonlinear and not well controlled so using such a diode in a voltage measuring circuit is not realistic.

The 500 Hz signal has an amplitude of roughly ± 5mV, but there is no easy way to access it. It is enclosed inside a medium that attenuates signals outside of 50-200 MHz, so I thought I could place a resonator at that frequency inside the medium and observe the change in resonant frequency through the medium to track the signal I can't observe. I'm hoping to use the varactor as a voltage-controlled capacitor, where the AC voltage of my signal acts as the 'voltage-control'

A good description of what you are trying to achieve and why maybe more useful than trying to find out how to use a method which may not be the optimum one.

In the circuit below, resonant frequency is determined by L1's inductance, and by Dvaractor's capacitance. C2 essentially grounds Dvaractor's cathode to L1's ground point. These three components (L1, C2, Dvaractor) must be placed in close proximity to reduce parasitic inductances and capacitances.
R1 and C1 need not be placed close-by, since C2 effectively grounds diode cathode at the very high resonant frequency (100 MHz).

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
 It is not apparent how you intend to probe the resonator, to determine its resonant frequency. It could be done with a coil tap or link winding, near its grounded end.
A DC bias is required so that the diode's cathode never drops below ground. If your AC signal amplitude is 1 volt peak-to-peak, at least plus one volt of DC bias is required.
Be aware that resonant frequency will be a non-linear with respect to AC signal amplitude. (Non-linear as well with respect to DC bias).

I don't fully understand why it is important that the diode's cathode never drops below ground—I do understand that the junction capacitance only occurs so long as there is a depletion region, and that remaining in reverse bias is the easiest way to ensure there is a depletion region. But it isn't there a slight range of forward bias voltages (ie: < ~700 mV for silicon) where the depletion region remains?
ie: if my AC signal peak to peak is 5 mV, and I were to operate with no DC bias voltage, I think this would preserve the junction capacitance of the varactor. Am I missing something?

You certainly don't need much DC bias if low-frequency AC input is only 5mV. Be aware that temperature coefficient of Dvaractor is significant at low DC bias so that resonant frequency drifts around. Capacitance versus volts is also very non-linear at low DC bias too.

5 mV AC signal will only cause a minuscule change in the capacitance of the varactor and therefor the resonant frequency. This will be quite hard to detect.  It will "work" in that the 500 Hz will modulate (FM) the resonance.
You might be able to supply RF power (at 50-200 MHz) to the medium, rectify it to get DC, and power an amplifier which then increases the 5 mV to ~ 10 V and use that to modulate the resonance ?

Your signal's "AC" is "DC" for the circuit.
The definition of these terms is a bit nebulous: it's context-sensitive.  It's generally DC when referring to baseband frequency behavior (in the limit down to 0Hz), and AC for anything above that.  Most circuits only have two bands of relevance (signal and DC) so this isn't very ambiguous, but what's AC for one part of a circuit might be DC for another, and so on.
Consider the equivalent circuits here:

Or if you prefer, leave the capacitors on the right side, so that the CRC lowpass filter is evident; this gives the cutoff boundary between equivalent circuits.
This motif (high and low frequencies enter on two ports, and combine at one) is called a bias tee.  Namely, the bias voltage to the varactor, and the RF current through it.  The RC (R, and the capacitor labeled C) is a basic bias tee.
Since the LC tank is resonant at some quite high frequency, a mere RC filter  will do for cutting between that and quite low frequencies (kHz say).  That is, an RC filter is quite gradual as a filter, but when you don't need much attenuation between ports (here, bias and RF) or the frequency range is wide, that's no problem.
If you're applying frequency modulation, you might well have an AC-coupled signal coming in, superimposed on the bias voltage; what might be "AC" in one part of the circuit, can be "DC" in another part.  A bit confusing, but it makes sense in time.
